# Testing with spek and sharing some base test-cases for base-classes

Tags: kotlin, spek

I'm using Spek as test framework, and have troubles when sharing some test-steps for base classes.

I have an abstract base class and two derived classes.

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract fun send()
}
class Foo : Base() {
    override fun send() {}
    fun anotherFunction() { }
}
class Bar : Base() {
    override fun send() {}
    fun differentFunction() { }
}
```

Now my question is: How can I create Speks for those classed, but only define the test for `send()` once in a base spek?

My **first approach** was to use `SubjectSpek`

```
class BaseSpek : SubjectSpek<Base>({
    subject {
        // ??? Can't instantiate Base because it is abstract
    }

    it("test the base") { ... }
})
class FooSpek : SubjectSpek<Foo>({
    itBehavesLike(BaseSpek)

    it("test anotherFunction") { ... }
})
```

My **second approach** was to use inheritance:

```
abstract class BaseSpek(base: Base) : Spek({
    it("test the base") { ... }
})
abstract class FooSpek() : BaseSpek(???)
```

It seems that none of my approaches works. Any suggestions how to solve this? Should I bring this to the attention of the Spek-Author for possible changes in future releases of Spek?

Comment: Please comment when you downvote. Authors should know what their mistake was, to write better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubjectSpek` is the correct approach.

```
abstract class BaseSpec: SubjectSpek<Base>({
    it("test base") { ... }
})

object FooSpec: BaseSpec<Foo>({
    subject { ... }

    // ugly for now, until Spek supports @Ignore
    itBehavesLike(object: BaseSpec() {})

    it("test another") { ... }
})
```